# How to add individual Owners to AAD app register using AZ module powershell script

Tags: owner, azure-app-registration, microsoft-entra-id, powershell-az-module

Unable to add owners into AAD app register using Az module powershell script
Using Below Script to add users on app.

```
$appName = "Sampleapp"
$ownerEmail = "user@outlook.com"

$app = Get-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName
if ($app) {
    $owner = Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName $ownerEmail
    if ($owner) {
        Add-AzADAppOwner -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId -OwnerObjectId $owner.Id
        Write-Host "Owner added successfully."
    } else {
        Write-Host "Owner with email $ownerEmail not found."
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Application with name $appName not found."
}
```

Getting below error
**
The term 'Add-AzADAppOwner' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
| included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
**

Unable to find the AZ command to add individual users in app register

[image]

Comment: @Rukmini,Thank you for your reply. After reviewing the provided response, I had attempted to utilize Azure module commands previously. However, I am currently exploring the migration of Azure commands to the Az module. Your comment has helped me realize that there are currently no Az module commands available. As a result, I have submitted an idea on the feedback platform at https://feedback.azure.com/d365community.

Answer (score 1):

Initially I got the **same error** as below:

```bash
$appName = "Sampleapp"
$ownerEmail = "user@outlook.com"

$app = Get-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName
if ($app) {
    $owner = Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName $ownerEmail
    if ($owner) {
        Add-AzADAppOwner -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId -OwnerObjectId $owner.Id
        Write-Host "Owner added successfully."
    } else {
        Write-Host "Owner with email $ownerEmail not found."
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Application with name $appName not found."
}
```

[image]

> **Note** that: There is no direct **`Az`** PowerShell command to add owners to the Azure AD application. Refer this [**GitHub blog**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9132)

Alternatively, you can make use of either [**AzureAD**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadapplicationowner?view=azureadps-2.0) or [**MicrosoftGraph**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/new-mgapplicationownerbyref?view=graph-powershell-1.0) or [**Az CLI**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/owner?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-owner-add) module to add owners to the group.

```
Connect-AzureAD

$appName = "RukTestApp"
$ownerEmail = "User@XXX.onmicrosoft.com"

# Fetch Azure AD application
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq '$appName'"

if ($app) {
    # Fetch the owner by email
    $owner = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $ownerEmail

    if ($owner) {
        # Add owner to the Azure AD application
        Add-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -RefObjectId $owner.ObjectId
        Write-Host "Owner added successfully."
    } else {
        Write-Host "Owner with email $ownerEmail not found."
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Application with name $appName not found."
}
```

[image]

***Owner added successfully to the Microsoft Entra application:***

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get Azure AD Application Owner (Get-AzADApplicationOwner) · Issue #1339 · MicrosoftDocs/feedback · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues/1339)